# error when building newly initialized addon

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

After I had troubles building/serving an addon I'm working at, I did the usual steps to heal (delete node_modules, npm clean, npm install, ...) with no success.
So finally I'm at the stage where I newly created a fresh addon via `ember addon jeff-table` to port the 'old' not working repo to there....
Addon-creation was successful:

> installing addon
>     create .bowerrc
>     ....
>     create .npmignore
>   Successfully initialized git.
>   Installed packages for tooling via npm.
>   Installed browser packages via Bower.

Anyway, again I get the same errors when trying to build the untouched addon:

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>      at EmberAddon.EmberApp._initVendorFiles (C:\users\jefff\google drive\www\ember-addons\jeff-table\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:317:55)
>      at EmberAddon.EmberApp [as appConstructor] (C:\users\jefff\google drive\www\ember-addons\jeff-table\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:94:8)
>      at new EmberAddon (C:\users\jefff\google drive\www\ember-addons\jeff-table\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-addon.js:38:8)
>      at module.exports (C:\users\jefff\google drive\www\ember-addons\jeff-table\ember-cli-build.js:6:13)
>      at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.setupBroccoliBuilder (C:\users\jefff\google drive\www\ember-addons\jeff-table\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:55:
>   19)
>      at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.init (C:\users\jefff\google drive\www\ember-addons\jeff-table\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:89:10)
>      at new Class (C:\users\jefff\google drive\www\ember-addons\jeff-table\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\core-object\core-object.js:18:12)
>      at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.run (C:\users\jefff\google drive\www\ember-addons\jeff-table\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\tasks\serve.js:15:19)
>      at C:\users\jefff\google drive\www\ember-addons\jeff-table\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\commands\serve.js:64:24

I suspected GDrive to have messed up my node_modules or smth, but on a fresh installation this could not be the case (with GDrive switched of).
I have not touched installation of ember-cli (not that I know of).

Does anybody have an idea of what could be wrong here?

ember-cli: 2.5.0
node: 4.2.2
os: win32 x64

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a lodash dependency in your package.json to a version older than 4.17.0.  It's a dependency of ember-cli and was updated last night.  I had the same error and stack trace with one of my company's projects this morning, it compiled last night in the CI system but failed this morning with no changes to the project.  I compared the downloaded dependencies, and a couple had new versions.  The first difference was lodash, so I added the 4.16.6 version to my package.json (the version that worked last night) and my project compiled again.

I'm still a novice when it comes to Node, so there may be a better solution, but this isn't the first time I was able to resolve a compilation break by forcing npm to get an older version of a dependency.

Comment: lodash isn't listed in package.json, so how can I set there? Shall I just add it as new dependency?

Answer (score 0):

the same issue hit my projects as well.

@Bloomy you are right,
error comes from here
/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:317:55
by short debugging it appear that the issue with accessing a property from an object which isn't exist, because, as I guess, lodash 'avoid deep cloning of ._omit result' https://github.com/lodash/lodash/commit/6c427b7a260183685b16d2624351529cda25ce81 .

If you will put version of lodash in ember-cli to some version which goes before (just for your local version) - you will see it works. Not possible for production yet. Going to open a ticket in ember-cli addon if isn't opened yet :)

Comment: 4.7.1 fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue and raised the following issue in github

https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/6432

And found out that the recent release of lodash i.e. `lodash@4.17.0` has a little bug in it which is breaking things. So till a patch is released, try using `lodash@4.16.5`, this should solve your problem for now.

Comment: could you guide me how I can use `lodash@4.16.5`? It's not listed in package.json and I'm still new (and confused) to that whole npm stuff...